# Spinner loads intent without waiting for selection from viewer

Tags: java, android

When the viewer selects an item from the spinner it should start a new intent.

BUT the app automaticly goes to the intent without waiting for the select. I thought the `onNothingSelected` was supposed to hold the app on the current activity until the user makes a selection. How do I fix this issue?

```
areaspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            int item = areaspinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("selection", item);

                   Intent myIntent = new Intent(patriosar.this, ShowXMLPAR.class);
                   myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                   startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);




        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this

```
private boolean mFirstSelect = true; //make this a field

areaspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            if (mFirstSelect)
            {
                  mFirstSelect = false;
                  return;
            }
            int item = areaspinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("selection", item);

                   Intent myIntent = new Intent(patriosar.this, ShowXMLPAR.class);
                   myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                   startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);




        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
```

Your select listener is getting fired when you set the values. This will prevent that from happening

Comment: I already had it checking what the first position (of my array in spinner) is and if it is "0" then do nothing. I just thought that is what onNothingSelect was for. lol Either way thanks for you feedback.

Comment: I'm not checking the position in the code I gave you. If you check if the position is 0 that is wrong. Whenever someone actually selects position 0, you won't get a result. You need to do what I did above and check if its the first time that event gets fired or not.